# How to pass a variable size 2-D array to a C function

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

This is something that is explained in multiple places on the internet, but for some reason the previously explained solutions do not seem to be working for me  I have an array of strings and I would like to pass the string array to a function that will print the array in a specific format.  The implementation is shown below, where `cols` represents the number of columns to print, and `length` represents the number of strings in the array.  The function should print the strings to column `col` and then continue printing on the next line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_string_vec(size_t cols, size_t length, char vec[][length]) {
    size_t rows;
    size_t temp = length;
    size_t ncols = cols;
    size_t index = 0;
    if (length % cols == 0) rows = length / cols;
    else rows = (length / cols) + 1;

    printf("[ ");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (temp <= cols) ncols = temp - 1;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
            printf("%s, ", vec[index]);
            index++;
        }
        temp -= ncols;
        if (temp == 1) break;
        printf("\n");
        printf("  ");
    }
    printf("%s ", vec[length - 1]);
    printf("]\n");
}

int main() {
    char a[][10] = {{"First"}, {"Second"}, {"Third"}, {"Fourth"},
                    {"Fifth"}, {"Sixth"}, {"Seventh"}, {"Eight"},
                    {"Nine"}, {"Tenth"}};
    print_string_vec(5, 10, a);
}
```

I am expecting the following output

```
[ First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth,
  Sixth, Seventh, Eighth, Ninth, Tenth ]
```

However this consistently fails in compile time with the following warning;

```
error: use of parameter outside function body before `]` token
```

Which indicates that it has a problem with passing a variable `length` to the muti-array instantiation.  If I replace this variable with `20` as a hard coded variable, it works fine, but then I have hard-coded a function to only work with one size array.  From what I can read this is an issue with compilers that are not C99 compliant, but mine is.   Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.  I am using gcc 12.1.0 and CMake to build the executable(s).  I have specified C99 and later versions as the minimum build type and I get the same results.

Comment: Post your compiler details - additionally you may need to pass `-std=c99` flag.

Comment: You pass the wrong dimension for the array, causing undefined behaviour. The `length` argument must be `20` as that is how you defined the array.   Then your function does some weird and confusing arithmetic . The call should be `print_string_vec(10, 20, a)` and the function should work with those values

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions I am using gcc 12.1.0 with CMake.  I have specified C99 and later versions in the CMake build and get the same results.

Comment: Jon, changing the question/code after answers arrive is poor SO etiquette.  Such moving targets attract down-votes.  Appending new info is good.

Comment: "use of parameter outside function body before" --> Perhaps a C++ compiler is used?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica this is a running issue with SO.  Different people have different ideas on what is appropriate SO etiquette.  I had two people reach out directly to me to let me know that to make the question appropriate for its intent, that the question needed to be updated.  Then you made a comment to the opposite.  I do not believe any updates that I made to the problem changed the intent of the question, in fact it made the question a bit more clear, and am not sure why that would be bad etiquette.

Comment: To not invalidate part of the first answer, your update could have posted an _appended_ updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` after `print_string_vec(5, 10, a)`.  And to compile the program you also need to include this header:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Your program then generates the following output:

```
[ First, , Second, , Third, 
  , Fourth, , Fifth,  ]
```

You declare `a[][20]` but use in the function as `a[][10]`.  If you change the declaration:

```
char a[][10] = { ... };
```

It now gets you the expected output.

Here is a more straight forward implementation:

```
void print_string_vec(size_t cols, size_t length, char vec[][length]) {
    enum { FIELD, LINE, LAST_LINE };
    const char *sep[] = {
        [FIELD] = ", ",
        [LINE] = ",\n  ",
        [LAST_LINE] = " "
    };
    printf("[ ");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%s%s",
            vec[i],
            sep[
                 !i || (i + 1) % cols ?
                     FIELD :
                     i + 1 < length ?
                         LINE :
                         LAST_LINE
            ]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

int main() {
    char a[][10] = {{"First"}, {"Second"}, {"Third"}, {"Fourth"},
                    {"Fifth"}, {"Sixth"}, {"Seventh"}, {"Eight"},
                    {"Nine"}, {"Tenth"}};
    print_string_vec(5, 10, a);
}
```

Comment: For brevity I did not include the `stdio.h` call in my problem statement, but it is in my actual program.  I adapted your approach and unfortunately received the same error.

Comment: Did you add the trailing missing ';' in the call to print_string_vec?  After you do, update question will the full  compiler error.  Make sure you use the code I gave you above.

Comment: Like the `stdio.h` call, that was just an omission in the manual transfer of the code to stackoverflow.  The ; you are referring to is and always was present in my actual code.  I did have an error in how I was passing 10 in the wrong place, but even with that fixed, it is still not accepting the syntax of passing `length` in the array declaration.